# My SlashCommands are getting doubled after making it Global commands

Tags: discord.js

[image: Screenshot of my slash commands]

As shown in the picture, my SlashCommands are getting doubled, every single one of them, and this happened when I changed `Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId)` to `Routes.applicationCommands(clientId)`

I'm pretty sure that the problem is in my 2 files

`interactionCreate.js`:

```js
const { CommandInteraction } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'interactionCreate',

  execute (interaction, client) {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    if (!command) {
      interaction.reply({content: 'Outdated Command', ephemeral: true});
    }
    command.execute(interaction, client);
  }
};
```

`commandHandler.js`:

```js
function loadCommands(client) {
    // const { loadFiles } = require('../functions/fileLoader');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const ascii = require('ascii-table');
    const table = new ascii().setHeading('Commands', 'Status');

    // await client.commands.clear();

    let commandsArray = [];

    // const Files = await loadFiles('../../commands');

    const commandsFolder = fs.readdirSync('/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/Commands');

    for (const folder of commandsFolder) {
        const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/Commands/${folder}`).filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for (const file of commandFiles) {
            const commandFile = require(`/Users/roopa/Desktop/projects/LLbot/src/Commands/${folder}/${file}`);

            client.commands.set(commandFile.data.name, commandFile);
            commandsArray.push(commandFile.data.toJSON());
            table.addRow(file, '');
            continue;
        }
    }

    return console.log(table.toString(), '\nCommands Loaded')
}
module.exports = { loadCommands };
```

Answer (score 2):

Your files are absolutely fine. The problem is that you registered all commands in a global scope **and** for your server (with the `guildId`). So the commands are only duplicated in this server. The `Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId)` will register commands only to a server while the `Routes.applicationCommands(clientId)` will register them globally, so you will need to decide which commands should be global accessible or only for a single server. If all commands should be accessible for one of the scopes, you can fix this by just [deleting the commands](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/deleting-commands.html#deleting-specific-commands) of the other scope. If you want to have global commands and a set of commands which should only be available for a single server, you will need to handle those commands separated.